# Parse doesn't work with cocoa pods "Use_Frameworks!"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm using `Cocoapods` in my project and I have a Swift pod I need to add, so I understood it requires the `use_frameworks!` statement in the PodFile.

The problem is that when I add this statement the `Parse` pod stops working, I can't understand why and how can I fix it.

Anyone had this problem and knows how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: It's `use_frameworks!`, not `Use_frameworks!`.

Comment: @tktsubota Yeah, that's what I mean...

Comment: create new project and see if the problem is with just this one project or your whole computer....

Comment: @MazelTov it's not just this project, it's a known problem

Comment: if it is know problem I believe there should be fix or any other information... I am using it and everything works great... I would check if you have latest, cocoapods and last "template" of the Podfile...